# How to open html code from server in uiwebview iOS objective c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have WebView. I am receiving redirect code from server as html and containing Javascript code. Now I would like it to open in uiwebview. However I can not deal with it.

I am receiving from server :

```
        <script id="sr8951237859">
        document.getElementById('mf72801224').submit();
        var element=document.getElementById('mf72844224');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        </script>
        <script>
        var e2=document.getElementById('sr22597859');
        e2.parentNode.removeChild(e2);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the content you are receiving from server in head tags and load it using loadHTMLString method as below

In swift:

```swift
let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><head>CONTENT_FROM_SERVER</head><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

In ObjC:

```c
NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head>CONTENT_FROM_SERVER</head><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>";
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I have already tried that.            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head> %@ </head> <body> </body> </html>", serverHTML];
   [_webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL: nil];  But still not working.

Comment: @ShakhzodBobokhonov You have to check what ever that javascript code does is doing it properly. Or you may have to load something in the body to actually be able to see something on web view

Comment: I am receiving this also before <script> </script> :                                                <form name="mf73168598" id="mf73168598" action="https://wi.web.uz/acquiring/hJaAGAA/Uz1239J6C6A7UtYScICvmVZ/middle/" method="post" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="N00wNGZLOFc2eCtkR3kzWEk1ZDhydz09" value="UTlCUHNQUXJFd0213YXcvdWxvUT09">
            <input type="hidden" name="09XYxdzUM1pwc9EQ1pmdNK123veNUPUq" value="36CP-_54ip$=">
            </form>

Comment: I tried to put <p> hello</p>. And I can see this in WebView

Comment: So you have to load your javascript methods somehow. Your issue is not related to iOS. You need to figure out what to load in the body based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use the "webViewDidFinishLoad" delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
  NSString* returnValue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"SCRIPT"];
  NSLog(@"returnValue = %@ ",returnValue);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me there is an issue from server side. I have tried this also. We tried it in android, and it works, but not in iOS